# Keep getting incorrect captcha

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

This used to work, but at some point in the last year it stopped working and we just found out today from a customer. It keeps on saying that you failed even if you type it right.

Also, if you press the voice button, it says a different number/word than the number/word it's displaying.

[Here is a live link.](http://www.homewetbar.com/tell_a_friend.php?products_id=822)

Comment: Reworded for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. For anyone else that has this problem the solution was...
The page had multiple tables. In an update, the end of the form got outside of the main table, breaking the captcha. Once the  was moved back inside the proper   it worked again!